# Error in different subpage of function which is not in use

Tags: javascript, html

I have weird error of function which I am not even using.
In one subpage I targeted all the child elements of and ID and it worked fine, but when I go to different subpage I get error in my console that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null. And I think now I have conflict in my other subpage.

This code is from subpage which is giving me problems:

```
var artistTags = document.getElementById('musicArtists').children;
document.getElementById('filterMusic').addEventListener('click', toggleFilter);
```

And now I am doing another function which is hiding certain elements while onclick. This is the code:

```
var scheduleFriday = document.getElementById('scheduleFriday').style.display = "block";
function toggleScheduleFriday() {

  resetAll();
  if (scheduleFriday == true) {
    document.getElementById('scheduleSunday').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('scheduleSaturday').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Any ideas guys, how to fix the problem with the child elements? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementById('musicArtists').children;` is a method call, it is being called. Is your script in the <head> or at end of your HTML page?

Comment: It is in seperate file scripts.js. However it is on line 1, does it make difference?

Comment: What makes a difference is where it is located on your HTML page.
Could you add the page code to your question, it would help.

Comment: It seems your script could not find element `musicArtists` on your HTML page, and the calling function `document.getElementById('musicArtists')` would return a null result. That is the reason the children property could not be accessed. Make sure on the page load event, script in the `scripts.js` you mentioned above can see that element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gqh9g0tw/ this is the working HTML page

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gqh9g0tw/1/ and this is the page where I get problems